# How to set the ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor in the ConsumerFactory?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, interceptor, confluent-platform

I have a Java spring boot Kafka consumer application and I am asked to use the confluent kafka's "ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor" to support the KAFKA replication

I have the below code however it is not working

```
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> entConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        log.info("connecting to enterprise consumer bootstrap server" + entBootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, entBootstrapAddress);
        log.info("using enterprise group id" + entGroupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, entGroupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");

// ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor: enables consumer applications to resume where they left off after a datacenter failover when using Confluent Replicator
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG, "io.confluent.connect.replicator.offsets.ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor");
    props.put("timestamp.producer.security.protocol", "PLAINTEXT");
    props.put("timestamp.producer.sasl.mechanism", "NONE");

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }
```

it throws the following warning

```
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.367 INFO 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig : ConsumerConfig values:
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] allow.auto.create.topics = true
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] auto.offset.reset = latest
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] bootstrap.servers = [17xxx:9092]
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] check.crcs = true
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] client.dns.lookup = default
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] client.id =
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] client.rack =
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] enable.auto.commit = true
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] exclude.internal.topics = true
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] fetch.min.bytes = 1
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] group.id = osps_dr
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] group.instance.id = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] interceptor.classes = [io.confluent.connect.replicator.offsets.ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor]
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] internal.leave.group.on.close = true
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] isolation.level = read_uncommitted
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] max.poll.records = 500
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] metric.reporters = []
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] metrics.num.samples = 2
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] metrics.recording.level = INFO
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] request.timeout.ms = 30000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] retry.backoff.ms = 100
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.jaas.config = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.class = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] send.buffer.bytes = 131072
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] session.timeout.ms = 10000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.cipher.suites = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.key.password = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.keystore.location = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.keystore.password = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.keystore.type = JKS
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.protocol = TLS
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.provider = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.truststore.location = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.truststore.password = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.truststore.type = JKS
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT]
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.388 INFO 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig : AdminClientConfig values:
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] bootstrap.servers = [17xxxx:9092]
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] client.dns.lookup = default
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] client.id = consumer-1
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] metric.reporters = []
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] metrics.num.samples = 2
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] metrics.recording.level = INFO
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] request.timeout.ms = 120000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] retries = 5
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] retry.backoff.ms = 100
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.jaas.config = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.class = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] send.buffer.bytes = 131072
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.cipher.suites = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.key.password = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.keystore.location = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.keystore.password = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.keystore.type = JKS
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.protocol = TLS
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.provider = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.truststore.location = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.truststore.password = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.truststore.type = JKS
2021-04-01T00:44:32.388+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT]
2021-04-01T00:44:32.446+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.446 WARN 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig : The configuration 'key.deserializer' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-04-01T00:44:32.446+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.446 WARN 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig : The configuration 'spring.json.trusted.packages' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-04-01T00:44:32.446+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.446 WARN 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig : The configuration 'value.deserializer' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-04-01T00:44:32.446+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.446 WARN 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig : The configuration 'enable.auto.commit' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-04-01T00:44:32.446+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.446 WARN 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig : The configuration 'group.id' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-04-01T00:44:32.446+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.446 WARN 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig : The configuration 'interceptor.classes' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-04-01T00:44:32.446+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.446 WARN 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig : The configuration 'timestamp.producer.security.protocol' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-04-01T00:44:32.446+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.446 WARN 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig : The configuration 'timestamp.producer.sasl.mechanism' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-04-01T00:44:32.449+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.449 INFO 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser : Kafka version: 2.3.1
2021-04-01T00:44:32.449+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.449 INFO 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser : Kafka commitId: 18a913733fb71c01
2021-04-01T00:44:32.449+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.449 INFO 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser : Kafka startTimeMs: 1617218072446
2021-04-01T00:44:32.452+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.452 INFO 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] i.c.connect.replicator.util.ReplicatorAdminClient : Requesting metadata refresh after 1 new topics were added
2021-04-01T00:44:32.454+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.454 INFO 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] i.c.c.r.offsets.ConsumerTimestampsWriterConfig : ConsumerTimestampsWriterConfig values:
2021-04-01T00:44:32.454+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] timestamps.producer.max.per.partition = 2147483647
2021-04-01T00:44:32.454+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] timestamps.producer.topic.blacklist = []
2021-04-01T00:44:32.454+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] timestamps.producer.topic.regex = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.454+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] timestamps.producer.topic.whitelist = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.454+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] timestamps.topic.num.partitions = 50
2021-04-01T00:44:32.454+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] timestamps.topic.replication.factor = 3
2021-04-01T00:44:32.454+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT]
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.712 INFO 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig : ProducerConfig values:
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] acks = all
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] batch.size = 16384
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] bootstrap.servers = [17xxxx:9092]
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] buffer.memory = 33554432
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] client.dns.lookup = default
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] client.id = consumer-1
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] compression.type = lz4
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] delivery.timeout.ms = 2147483647
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] enable.idempotence = false
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] interceptor.classes = []
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] key.serializer = class io.confluent.connect.replicator.offsets.GroupTopicPartitionSerializer
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] linger.ms = 500
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] max.block.ms = 60000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] max.request.size = 10485760
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] metric.reporters = []
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] metrics.num.samples = 2
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] metrics.recording.level = INFO
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] request.timeout.ms = 30000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] retries = 2147483647
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] retry.backoff.ms = 500
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.jaas.config = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.class = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] send.buffer.bytes = 131072
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.cipher.suites = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.key.password = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.keystore.location = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.keystore.password = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.keystore.type = JKS
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.protocol = TLS
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.provider = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.truststore.location = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.truststore.password = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ssl.truststore.type = JKS
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] transactional.id = null
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] value.serializer = class io.confluent.connect.replicator.offsets.TimestampAndDeltaSerializer
2021-04-01T00:44:32.712+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT]
2021-04-01T00:44:32.744+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.744 WARN 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig : The configuration 'key.deserializer' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-04-01T00:44:32.744+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.744 WARN 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig : The configuration 'value.deserializer' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-04-01T00:44:32.744+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.744 WARN 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig : The configuration 'group.id' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-04-01T00:44:32.744+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.744 WARN 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig : The configuration 'spring.json.trusted.packages' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-04-01T00:44:32.745+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.744 WARN 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig : The configuration 'enable.auto.commit' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-04-01T00:44:32.745+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.744 WARN 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig : The configuration 'timestamp.producer.security.protocol' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-04-01T00:44:32.745+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.744 WARN 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig : The configuration 'timestamp.producer.sasl.mechanism' was supplied but isn't a known config.
```

Status in the Primary KAFKA cluster

[image]

Status in the Secondary KAFKA cluster

[image]

Ideally the offset in both the Primary & Secondary KAFKA cluster should be in sync which is not happening.

What am I missing?

**Note:** I have another simple application that uses the below configuration and the ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor works for this app.

```
spring:
  kafka:
    properties:
      bootstrap.servers: ${vcap.services.sp-kv.credentials.kafkaservers}
    consumer:
      properties:
        interceptor:
          classes: io.confluent.connect.replicator.offsets.ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor
        timestamp:
          producer:
            security:
              protocol: PLAINTEXT
            sasl:
              mechanism: NONE
```

Answer (score 1):

The interceptor is being applied ok.

`>2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] interceptor.classes = [io.confluent.connect.replicator.offsets.ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor]`.

You can ignore those WARN logs; it's just the `AdminClientConfig` warning about unknown configs; you seem to have applied the consumer configs to an `AdminClient`. Maybe it's the interceptor itself.

[[Start Speculation]]

I am not familiar with the interceptor, but I would guess that the offsets would be corrected until after the failover. It looks like it writes to the `__consumer_timestamps` topic.

Presumably it uses that to sync up the proper offset later.

[[End Speculation]]

Comment: Yes, it  writes to the "__consumer_timestamps" topic which is read by replicator to sync the offset however offset is not getting sync'd leaving unbalanced offset between the Kafka clusters.

If the interceptor is applied, it should sync the offsets. Not sure what is missed?

Comment: Well, the question is about how to set the interceptor and that is correct. You might be better off asking a more targeted question about the replication mechanism now that you know the consumer has got the interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Offsets in Primary KAFKA cluster and Secondary KAFKA cluster are different. If you are using compacted topics, offset in Primary KC will be greater than offset in Secondary KC.